# Setting Ember.Button text in Ember.js view

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In the `Ember.js` app that I'm working on, I'm defining a view in my `App.js` file:

```
RateEditor.DeleteTierView = Em.View.extend({
  classNames: ['delete-tier-view'],
  tagName: 'button',
  click: function () {
    var tier = this.get('content');
    var controller = this.getPath('contentView.content');
    controller.get('content').removeObject(tier);
  }
});
```

The view displays correctly as a `button` and the `click` function is working fine. But I can't figure out how to set the text of the `button`, so it's just blank.

Is there a property that lets you set the text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create this:

```
  <button class="ember-view delete-tier-view">Click Me</button>
```

Do this:

```
  {{#view RateEditor.DeleteTierView}}Click Me{{/view}}
```

Comment: Thanks, Dan. I had declared the `button` this way originally, but I wasn't aware I could combine this syntax with the code-declared version.

Comment: Heh, what a coincidence. Just before I posted this, I found your Beginning Ember.js blog post series. Taking a look now...

Comment: Glad to help, Josh. BTW, I found the examples at handlebarsjs.com useful when I was getting started with templates.

Comment: I'd still be interested in setting the text of a Button directly in the View definition. Is that possible?